# Create a named range based on referenced

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to create a dropdown list that displays a list based on values of a reference  table.

I have a two columns in a Table (NAMETYPES):

```
    A           B
1   Name 1      M
2   Name 2      F    
3   Name 3      M
4   Name 4      M
5   Name 5      F
6   Name 6      F
```

What formula would I need to create a two named ranges that breaks up NAMETYPES by its Reference column?

Result:

```
   M Range     F Range
   Name 1      Name 2
   Name 3      Name 5     
   Name 4      Name 6
```

The NAMETYPES table will be continuously updated, so I'm trying to avoid hardcoding the range. I would I would also like to avoid VBA if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: you would just select M or F in the dropdowns?

Comment: No, whatever names in the M or F range need to appear. I have a bootstrapped solution I made with name ranges using filtered pivot tables, but I believe this will be memory intensive.

Comment: No more memory intensive than the needed Array type formulas you would need to accomplish this.  If memory is a concern then VBA is your answer.  Pivot Tables will be less memory than the formula route.